# What language is cortana programmed in?

Tags: cortana

I need to know the above so I can understand how conrtana works. If I say, open media player, what are the key lines of code where Cortana is programmed to follow a path to a file?

Answer (score 0):

It's an AI which was developed using a new language and GUI and an API (Application Programming Interface) for the web. Its development framework has been so hidden but its 'rumored' that it is has borrowed bits from languages such as python and java. Microsoft Cortana is written mostly C#.

You can follow this reddit thread.
[In what programming language is "Cortana" written?](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/7ao883/in_what_programming_language_is_cortana_written/)

P.S:- This answer is pasted from google.

After reading the comment it got me thinking why you want to know this. So I am pasting some links which I think will be useful to you.

[Build Cortana Skills](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana)

[Cortana Skills Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/overview)

[Creating Cortana Skill set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/mva22-hello-world)

Comment: Is this really a question about protocol handlers or launching local executables via Cortana?  You can build skills to launch anything (via deep link) that has a protocol handler, and you can build handlers to launch executables given a path to a local file (on windows).